# Is it 27K or 271K km?

Tags: tachometer

The owner of this car says that his car has 27 thousand KM but to me it looks like 271 thousand km. Am I mistaken or he?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mileage shown there is 271000 ie 271k km.

The rationale is that the total distance counter is always integer ie whole numbers.

You  could get him to take you for a test drive and discuss why the 6 changes to a 7 then 8 in kilometers not every 100 metres...

The distance shown on trip counters always shows a single decimal. Ie 345.1 km

He is trying to get one over on you, walk away - I would not trust him. Do the seats show wear especially the drivers seat or has it just been replaced? Perfect condition... what about the carpets - heel wear marks beneath the pedals? What does the servicing documentation show? There should be a continuity - or is that “missing” ???